# How to run Scrapy/Portia on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, scrapy, portia

I am trying to run Scrapy or Portia on a Microsoft Azure Web App.
I have installed Scrapy by creating a virtual environment:

```
D:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe D:\home\Python
```

And then installed Scrapy:

```
D:\home\Python\Scripts\pip install Scrapy
```

The installation seemed to work. But executing a spider returns the following output:

```
D:\home\Python\Scripts\tutorial>d:\home\python\scripts\scrapy.exe crawl example 2015-09-13 23:09:31 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: tutorial)

2015-09-13 23:09:31 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11

2015-09-13 23:09:31 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}

2015-09-13 23:09:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState

Unhandled error in Deferred:

2015-09-13 23:09:35 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command

    cmd.run(args, opts)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run

    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 153, in crawl

    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator

    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())

--- <exception caught here> ---

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks

    result = g.send(result)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 71, in crawl

    self.engine = self._create_engine()

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 83, in _create_engine

    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 66, in __init__

    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 65, in __init__

    self.handlers = DownloadHandlers(crawler)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 23, in __init__

    cls = load_object(clspath)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object

    mod = import_module(module)

  File "D:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module

    __import__(name)

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\s3.py", line 6, in <module>

    from .http import HTTPDownloadHandler

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 5, in <module>

    from .http11 import HTTP11DownloadHandler as HTTPDownloadHandler

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 15, in <module>

    from scrapy.xlib.tx import Agent, ProxyAgent, ResponseDone, \

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\xlib\tx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

    from twisted.web import client

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 42, in <module>

    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, SSL4ClientEndpoint

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 34, in <module>

    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>

    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio

  File "D:\home\Python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 7, in <module>

    import win32api

exceptions.ImportError: No module named win32api



2015-09-13 23:09:35 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

The documentation http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html says that I have to install **pywin32**. I don't know how I can download/install it via command line since I am in the web app environment.

Is it even possible to run Scrapy or Portia on an Azure Web App or do I have to use a fully fledged Virtual Machine on Azure?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that you could run your spider from [Scrapy Cloud](http://scrapinghub.com) (there's a free plan and disclaimer: working there). You can then use the API or an outright dump to get your data.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run general purpose Windows applications "on" an Azure Web App. Things that run on Azure as web apps have to be built specifically to do so.
So, you have to use a full-fledged Virtual Machine on Azure.

It seems Azure Webapps can run some Python apps, if they are built on certain frameworks:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/