# Deploy Scrapy to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, ssh, scrapy, virtual-machine

I made a crawler with Scrapy who send his outputs in a Parse server.

Moreover I created a virtual Machine in Microsoft Azure to store my crawler and make some cron jobs.

I'm lost I created my virtual Machine **and I don't understand where and how I put my crawler in ?**

I've already checked this tutorial http://sertacozercan.com/2013/08/how-to-do-basic-web-scraping-using-scrapy-on-windows-azure/

Thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the VM Dashboard, do a RDP to your VM & search out there. Lemme know if you need any help from my end.

Good luck & hope it helps.

Comment: I'm connected in my VM but the problem is how I deploy my Scrapy project in my VM ?

Comment: Is it a Linux / Windows VM?

Comment: This q's has already been asked refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555510/how-to-run-scrapy-portia-on-azure-web-app